# Pass parameter into Index.html Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly. I like to pass a variable while runtime from a razor component to the client index html.

Index.html Pseudo Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://example{myparameter}.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Index Html Pseudo Code:

```
@code 
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        PassPararemter();
    }
    public void PassPararemter()
    {
        //Get value from Database
        data = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<string>($"api/example");
        Do send-to - indexhtml
    }
}
```

And ask myself if it is possible?

Comment: Do you want to conditionally load a script into the page after the SPA has started, based on say the route?  Say charts.js if your using charts on a page.  Or are you looking for a way to manipulate the header information after the SPA has started?

Comment: Dig here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-rc-1/#blazor-templates-updated-to-set-page-title, perhaps you find something that can help you

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis manipulate the header information after the SPA has started. As in my pseudocode shown i want to manipulate the header and change here for example the {myparameter}-part during runtime. Or at least, if its not possible otherwise, after restart the SPA